# Flask App only returns 404's regardless of how it is run

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I can't seem to get my app running correctly on uWSGI. I've taken nginx out of the equation by running uWSGI from the command line and it exhibits the exact same behavior as it does while running on nginx.

```
uwsgi -s 0.0.0.0:5050 -w app:app --uid www-data --gid www-data --protocol=http
```

And uwsgi handles the request as follows:

```
[pid:0625|app: 0|req: 1/1] 192.168.1.219 () {34 vars in 737 bytes} [Tue Mar 31 11:10:30 2015] GET /admin => generated 233 bytes in 25 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 3 headers in 249 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

My file structure is below

```
/srv/www/cc/app/
               static/
               templates/
               __init__.py
               views.py
               models.py
               forms.py
```

In light of new evidence that it may be my app, Here's my **init**.py file:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

from flask.ext.mail import Mail
mail = Mail(app)

from app import models, forms

#setup flask-security
from flask.ext.security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore

user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, models.User, models.Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore,
    confirm_register_form = forms.ExtendedConfirmRegisterForm
    )

from app import views
```

Link to my entire views.py: http://pastebin.com/0jMTarEe

I've had this same app, way earlier in development, running on a different nginx+uwsgi server I had, and have copied their configuration files exactly but to no avail. I really am at a loss for why this will not work. But according to the Flask documentation, the above is all I should need.

For giggles, I went ahead and removed uwsgi from the equation as well. Created a run.py file in the cc folder... python run.py:

```
from app import app
app.run('0.0.0.0', port=5050, debug=True)
```

And the request:

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5050/
* Restarting with reloader
192.168.1.219 - - [31/Mar/2015 11:56:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

So it appears to be a problem with my app somehow, rather than anything regarding nginx or uwsgi. I'm not getting any errors anywhere though... what can be going wrong??

*EDIT*

Did more digging via suggestions from the comments. I've edited the bottom of my **init**.py:

```
import . import views

print views
print app.url_map
```

And here's the output when I start my server:

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5050/
* Restarting with reloader
<module 'app.views' from '/srv/www/cc/app/views.py'>
Map([<Rule '/' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> index>,
<Rule '/admin/' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> admin>,
<Rule '/test/' (HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, GET) -> test>
...
Lots more ... ])
```

Comment: It seems like you are never loading your views/routes/blueprints. I wonder if changing `from app import views` to `from . import views` works(?)

Comment: @adarsh I agree. I've added some print statements in my files though, and it appears to be correctly entering my view.py file. If I'm not getting any errors during import, can I not assume all went to plan?

Comment: Can you inspect `app.url_map` in your `__init__.py`? (after importing view of course)

Comment: @adarsh updated topic with your suggestions.

Comment: Weird, the routes seem to be registered to the app. Can you show me your view file? (Partly if not entirely)

Comment: @adarsh Yessir, here you are: http://pastebin.com/0jMTarEe

Comment: I don't know if this would help, but have you tried removing the trailing slash `/` from the routes?

Comment: @adarsh Gave it a shot, but no dice. Thanks anyway :*(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set the `SERVER_NAME` config value, it *must* match the host and port that the app is being externally served on. Either comment it out, or make it match the domain or ip of the server.

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com:80'
```

When running the dev server, the name would be `localhost:5000`, although setting it in that case is typically not necessary.